# Running a script that contains git commands using `git submodule foreach` causes a `not a git repository` error

Tags: bash, git, git-submodules

I'm using a few git submodules in my project, each with their own dependencies. I'm running the top level `setup.sh`, which installs top level deps and then runs this, which calls each submodule's `setup.sh` script.

```
git submodule foreach 'if [ -e "setup.sh" ]; then ${SUDO} "`pwd`/setup.sh"; fi'
```

That runs fine, but the problem arises when the `sub1` and `sub2` submodules call their own `setup.sh` script that does the exact same thing.
When any git command is run by the `sub1` and `sub2` `setup.sh` script, it fails with the error:

```
fatal: not a git repository: '.git'
```

`pwd` in the `sub1` and `sub2` scripts give me the correct path, and the scripts work fine in isolation.

Project structure:

```
.
├── setup.sh
└── submodules
    ├── sub1
    |   ├── setup.sh
    |   └── submodules
    |       └── sub3
    |           └── setup.sh
    └── sub2
        ├── setup.sh
        └── submodules
            └── sub4
                └── setup.sh
```

Apologies if this is a stupid question, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just a guess but try `unset GIT_DIR; if [ -e "setup.sh" ]; ...` (fill in the `...` part with the rest - basically just unset `GIT_DIR` at the front of the foreach command).

Comment: (If this works, that seems like a bug in `git submodule foreach` to me)

Comment: @torek you should make that an answer.

Comment: @kzh: Done. Took me a while to find `--local-env-vars` again first, though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When a command works fine on its own, but not in a `git submodule foreach`, my first suspect is that some of Git's environment variables are "leaking out" and affecting the command.  The most common here is `GIT_DIR`, so replacing:

```
git submodule foreach 'some command'
```

with:

```
git submodule foreach 'unset GIT_DIR; some command'
```

will often get around the problem.

You can get a complete list of such variables with:

```
git rev-parse --local-env-vars
```

There's a shell script included with Git, `git-sh-setup`, that has this in it:

```sh
# Clear repo-local GIT_* environment variables. Useful when switching to
# another repository (e.g. when entering a submodule). See also the env
# list in git_connect()
clear_local_git_env() {
        unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
}
```

and this single-line `unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)` command will unset *all* potentially-problematic environment variables, so if `unset GIT_DIR` is insufficient, `unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)` is the bigger hammer.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Some people say "if it ain't broke, don't fix it," but others say ["if it ain't broke, you need a bigger hammer."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kO0fg-Yg_sA)